# Android using animation to make an object fall towards the ground using gravity

Tags: java, android, animation, gravity

I am new to Android development and I am trying to create an image at the top of the screen and make it fall to the bottom. I have been looking around and cannot get a straight answer or pointer in the correct direction. A lot of the examples I am finding are out of date and many of the methods don't work any more.

I have an image in my drawable folder that I would like to create after 10 seconds and have it fall towards the ground like it has gravity.

I have seen a lot about ObjectAnimator, canvas, velocity, animation. I am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be sure to check out the [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) class and its methods.
For acceleration and bouncing etc. there are so called Interpolators, to make Animations more lifelike / realistic. The simplest way I can think of would be something like this :

Lets say you have a RelativeLayout as Parent and an ImageView as a child in a xml file like this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/your_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then start the Animation like this in your Java Code :

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_image);

float bottomOfScreen = getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
    .heightPixels - (imageView.getHeight() * 4);
        //bottomOfScreen is where you want to animate to

imageView.animate()
    .translationY(bottomOfScreen)
    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator())
    .setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator())
    .setDuration(2000);
```

That should get you started.

Comment: Any  chance you have some sources for those for me  to follow? :) Thank you very much by the way

Comment: What do you mean? Tutorials?

Comment: Oh  Sorry never mind you said what is was 'ViewPropertyAnimator'. Thanks Again!

Comment: Thanks, On a Side note any chance you know how to do collision? When my image falls down I want it bounce of a linearLayout. I have seen a few Using rect.intersect however It does not seem to work for me

Comment: Will do later today, thanks again this is very good information that you entered as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate *real* gravity, it's very hard and it requires you to install other external libraries. You will also need to do a lot of maths in order to get the gravity working.

<sub>real gravity: things will accelerate and bounce and other stuff</sub>

But if you just want something to fall from the top to bottom at constant speed (no accelerations), it's easier.

You just need to make a new xml file in the `anim` folder of your project and load it up in your code. There are a lot of tutorials to do this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

It's really easy! (XML stuff is always easy, isn't it?)

Comment: I see some advantages however as the levels increase I want to be able  to increase the speed as well as make it appear randomly on the x at the very top of the screen

Comment: Is there also a way to simulate a ;bouncing effect'?

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt:

```
Handler h=new Handler();
ImageView img;

Runnable r= new Runnable()
        {
        @Override public void run() {img.invalidate();}
        };

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle b)
{
    super.onCreate(b);
    p.setColor(Color.RED);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    p.setDither(false);
    p.setStrokeWidth(3);
    p.setAntiAlias(true);       
    p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
    p.setStrokeWidth(15);
    p.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);    
    p.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

    img=new ImageView(this)
        {   
            @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas cnv)
            {
                x+=i;
                y+=j;
                if(x>300)i=-1;
                if(y>300)j=-1;
                if(x<0)i=1;
                if(y<0)j=1;

                cnv.drawPoint(x,y,p);
                h.postDelayed(r,fps);
```

The point is that we need to call updates to user interface main thread from an outside handle handling the running thread at fixed fps.

For full code check here:
[Thread Runnable Handle to Graphic Animation Bouncing Ball like Pixels](https://letsmakeandroidapp.wordpress.com/step-8-thread-of-animation-the-moving-graphic-at-fixed-fps/)